# Add or remove checked items from checkedlistbox to listbox

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

I kind of new in C#, my problem is how to add checked items from a checkedlistbox to a listbox, and when I uncheck this item remove it from the listbox also..
Thanks!

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: i was using a foreach, in the adding part works great, but the problem began with unchecking the item and removing from the listbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `checkedListBox1` as `checkedListBox` and your `listBox` called `listBox1`, you should add this `ItemCheck Event` for your `checkedListBox`

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    listBox1.Items.Add(checkedListBox1.Items[checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex]);
  if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
    listBox1.Items.Remove(checkedListBox1.Items[checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex]);
}
```

Comment: check Events tab of your checkedListBox, ItemCheck Event should point to this method

Answer (score 1):

Add Items :

```
YourListbox.Items.Add("");
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add.aspx

Delete Items :

```
YourListbox.Items.Remove("");
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.remove.aspx

```
var items = new System.Collections.ArrayList(listboxFiles.SelectedItems);

foreach (var item in items) {
        listbox.Items.remove(item);

}
```

Comment: how can I use itemcheck event in this case?

Comment: you use selectedItems in order to select

Comment: I'm using this code, but it seems that debugger doesnt execute the item check event.

public void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
            {
               
                listBox1.Items.Add(checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            }
        }
        
        private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Text = checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

Comment: I used a breakpoint in the chekedlistbox1_itemcheck event but it doesnt seem to be hit by the debugger.

Comment: Check that you have added your delegate

Answer (score 0):

ASPX

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="_CheckBoxList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:ListBox ID="_ListBox" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

CS

```
protected void CheckBoxList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBoxList cbx = (CheckBoxList)sender;

    _ListBox.Items.Clear();
    foreach (ListItem item in cbx.Items)
    {
        if(item.Selected)
            _ListBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.Text, item.Value));
    }

}
```

Wrap it in an Update Panel to use AJAX